# How to integrate smartcard with my c# application?

Tags: c#, integration, development-environment, smartcard, apdu

I want to develop a C# application that login the user/ provide authentication function using SmartCard (Gemalto IDPrime MD 830).

I have basic knowledge of APDU commands that are used to communicate with SmartCard.

I am unable to integrate the SmartCard with my C# application.

How can I start the authentication process as I need to communicate with Card first?

Comment: Check if this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885 is helpful...